# How to get combineReducers working with flowtype?

Tags: redux, flowtype

I want to use the combineReducers function from redux.
However I get the following error message:

```
Missing type annotation for `A`. `A` is a type parameter declared in function type [1] and was implicitly instantiated
at call of `combineReducers` [2].

   src/reducer/index.js:12:16
   12| export default combineReducers({ message })
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ [2]

References:
   flow-typed/npm/redux_v4.x.x.js:56:42
   56|   declare export function combineReducers<O: Object, A>(reducers: O): CombinedReducer<$ObjMap<O, <S>(r: Reducer<S, any>) => S>, A>;
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ [1]
```

My reducer is just a function taking a state and an action and returning
a new state.

Then I just call `combineReducers` on the reducer as shown in the error message.

Does anybody know an **easy** fix to this?

Answer (score 5):

I have found the solution.

Somehow you must type the result of the reducer.
You can actually do two things, the first one is:

```
export default combineReducers<*, *>({ message })
```

For me this feels like a hack.
The better solution is:

```
type State = {
    message: MessageState
}
const reducers: Reducer<State, Action> = combineReducers({ message })
export default reducers
```

This however requires you to keep track of the type of your state and actions,
which you should do anyway.

Comment: `*` is deprecated and should be avoided. Your second recommendation is correct.

Comment: Link for reference https://flow.org/en/docs/linting/rule-reference/#toc-deprecated-type